# How many functions from $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ have $\phi(ab) = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations, natural-numbers, semigroups, semigroup-homomorphism

How many maps $\phi : \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}  \to \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ are there, with the property that $\phi(ab) = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$, $\forall a, b$ $\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$?

Can I get a hint to solve this problem?

I have noticed that $\phi(0) = 0$ because $\phi(0\cdot0) =2\phi(0) \implies \phi(0) =0$,
$\phi(a\cdot0)= \phi(a)+\phi(0)\implies \phi(0)=\phi(a)$

So one of the map is one which sends every element to 0. How to check if there are other maps satisfying the above condition?

Comment: You proved $\phi (0) = \phi (a) = 0$ using nothing but the given relations so every possible map is the zero map. You're done.

Comment: Now I realise it, thank you.

Comment: FWIW, the question is more interesting if 0 is not in the domain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many maps $\phi:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$ are there with $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)+\phi(b)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603144/how-many-maps-phi-bbbn-to-bbbn-are-there-with-phiab-phia-phib)